# How to check for proxy settings in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Am trying to find out how can I check, if proxy is being used in the computer via Inno Setup.

Comment: What for? The Inno Download Plugin autodetects the proxy on its own, doesn't it?

Comment: Am not sure it does or not but what am trying to do is use it as a trigger for some event inside the scrip so i would like to know how i can display a message if proxy is being used.

Comment: Also itdownloader is not working when i tried that any idea why?

Comment: When you tried what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpgetdefaultproxyconfiguration):

```pascal
type
  WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO = record
    AccessType: Cardinal;
    Proxy: Cardinal;
    ProxyBypass: Cardinal;
  end;

function WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration(var ProxyInfo: WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO): Boolean;
  external 'WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration@winhttp.dll stdcall';

function StrCpyN(S1: string; S2: Cardinal; Max: Cardinal): Cardinal;
  external 'StrCpyNW@shlwapi.dll stdcall';

function GetProxy: string;
var
  ProxyInfo: WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO;
begin
  if WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration(ProxyInfo) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, 1024);
    StrCpyN(Result, ProxyInfo.Proxy, Length(Result) - 1);
    Result := Trim(Result);
    Log('Retrieved proxy information: ' + Result);
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Cannot retrieve proxy information');
  end;
end;
```

*Requires [Unicode Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).*

---

You can also use `netsh winhttp show proxy` command.

Comment: perfectly working. Thanks to you and to this wonderful platform.